# How to add .erb file in existing model in rhoMobile

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I have created a simple application and edited the index.erb file so that I have a simple view with a text box and a button.

Now when i click on that button i want it to navigate to a new view.
I know that we can add models and in that models we have different .erb files.
but i want to create a single .erb file or add it to an existing model so that i can change edit the view and call that view as i press the button.

Is it like for every screen we have to create a model??

I dont know how to do the same, i tried searching but no help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that for every screen you've to create a model rather the reverse. Every model for which you need interfaces you'll create views.

Why don't you start with [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and move ahead understanding the basics.

Other than CRUD interfaces? You can add a view file directly to the view folder of the controller this model is associated with. For example, if the model is post.rb in `app/models` and it has a corresponding controller `posts_controller.rb` in `app/controllers` and it has corresponding views in `app/views/posts` then you can add your view to `app/views/posts` folder with a corresponding method in the controller which will render that view provided there is a route for that in the `config/routes.rb` file.

Say I want to add a `landing_page.html.erb` view to Post. I would add a method in `posts_controller.rb` (although, this is not mandatory. But, might be useful for you to check some conditions before rendering the view):

```
class posts_controller < ApplicationController
  ...
  def landing_page
  end
end
```

Add a view in app/views/posts directory:

```
# app/views/posts/landing_page.html.erb
```

Add a route to the config/routes.rb file:

```
map.resources do
  member do
    get :landing_page
  end
end
```

Now, you can access the page at `http://localhost:3000/posts/:id/landing_page`.

Comment: means you want to say that we can add a .erb file where i can design my view in html?? but how do i add it

Answer (score 3):

No you don't have to create models for each view(.erb). In case you want to add new view to existing model, just add new method(def) into the controller(.rb), and new view(.erb) with the same name as of the new method.

let say there exist a model DemoController.rb in app/Demo. you can add new method to it as like

```
class DemoController < Rho::RhoController
  ...
  def index
  end

  def new_method
  end

end
```

To navigate from the index view to the new_method, you can write

```
<button onclick="location.href='/app/Demo/new_method'">new method</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="location.href='<%= url_for :action => :new_method %>'"
>new method</button>
```